# Writing or generating lenses for nonrecord datatypes

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I have a nonrecord `newtype` which I would like to generate the lenses for:

```hs
newtype Foo = Foo (Int, String)
```

I would like to make a named lenses for it, currently I'm doing manually like follows:

```hs
bar :: Lans' Foo Int
bar = lens
  (\(Foo (x, y)) -> x)
  (\(Foo (x,y)) x' -> Foo (x', y))
```

I would prefer either using some TH magic here or at least more sophisticated syntax like:

```hs
bar :: Lens' Foo Int
bar = Foo <$> _1
```

Is it somehow possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably looking for `Control.Lens.Wrapped` to handle the newtype.  You can construct a `Wrapped` instance via generics:

```
newtype Foo = Foo (Int, String) deriving (Generic)
instance Wrapped Foo
```

and can then write:

```
bar :: Lens' Foo Int
bar = _Wrapped' . _1
```

Comment: The empty instance can be replaced with [`deriving anyclass Wrapped`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/derive_any_class.html#extension-DeriveAnyClass).